# A problem with a Python function to modify the information in the database

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I wrote a Python function to modify the data and information entered in the database

```
def update(self):
        con = pymysql.connect(
            host = 'localhost',
            user = 'root',
            password = '',
            database = 'employ')
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("update employees set family_members=%s, social_status=%s, gender=%s, date_birth=%s, id_number=%s, mail=%s, name=%s where id=%s",(
                    self.family_members_var.get(),
                    self.social_status_var.get(),
                    self.gender_var.get(),
                    self.date_birth_var.get(),
                    self.id_number_var.get(),
                    self.mail_var.get(),
                    self.name_var.get(),
                    self.id_var.get()
                    ))
        con.commit()
        self.fetch_all()
        self.clear()
        con.close()
```

I got the following error:

> pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1")

Comment: The SQL seems OK, so better post sample data for those variables to reproduce the issue.  Also post the table definition of `employees`.

Comment: Please explain more with some examples

Comment: What I said is that the SQL statement seems OK.  It means that I don't know why you got the error, so how can I provide an example?  Also there is no `)` in the SQL as mentioned in the error you post, so I wonder the posted code is not the issue.

Comment: I am surprised that this unexpected error occurred
Because there are other functions such as adding and deleting work well in the program
Only this function (modification function) does not do its work and gives Error!!